# Where can I buy a wide range of used bike parts online?

Tags: frugal, parts, build

Does anyone know of a reputable website that sells a wide range of used and second hand bike parts and components?

I'm helping a friend rebuild an older commuter bike and we are having trouble finding compatible components. There are a couple of local shops that carry used parts, but not having any luck there so far. I know of an Ebay seller that sells used ski equipment; I'm wondering if, likewise, there is a website for used bike parts. I'm basically looking for a larger inventory than my local area.

Comment: "I know of an Ebay site" ? Do you mean an eBay seller? Because there is plenty of second hand bike stuff on eBay. I would recommend it.

Comment: Yes. Ebay seller. Hoping to find a seller or other site with a large selection.

Comment: The ski equip Ebay store has a warehouse full of equip. I'd like to find something like that for bike related to avoid having to search and pick through stuff and also looking for a good rep.

Comment: I know no site but if you can find a bicycle club, it is probably a way to go. I am in one and people often share free old second-hand parts. The good side is that the club can be much more than that like bulk-purchase-organizer, touring-trip-organizer, random-competition-organizer, sponsor-finding-assistance-to-competition -- and much more. I like it because it saves me time, money -- and it is fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Loose Screws Small Bicycle Parts](https://www.loosescrews.com/) has a decent selection of small parts.

Comment: This worked. I clicked and scrolled and found the item I was looking for.

Comment: The current link takes me to a Japanese site about loaning credit cards? [Here is an updated link](https://www.loosescrews.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Ebay and craigslist, and maybe amazon is pretty much it. Otherwise you can try bikeforums or mtbr for sale subforums in addition to local shops.

Answer (score 2):

I've not had any luck consistently finding used parts online.  For used commuter/entry-level stuff the best source I've found is local garage sales.  For used nicer stuff try your local racing clubs.  They tend to discard nice stuff, for cheap, on a regular basis as they always need the latest greatest to go the fastest.  Surprisingly the local touring bike clubs have not been a great source as those people seem to hold onto stuff forever.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was asked, Facebook marketplace has really taken off, and there are sales/wants groups but local and long distance. Some can be very specialised. Enthusiasts' groups often have an associated buying and selling group, or permit such requests.